# Intercept data from observable before binding it to another observer

Tags: rx-swift, swift5

I have a observable that emits data which looks something like this:

```swift
struct AlertData {
    let name: String
    let actionStream: PublishSubject<Void>
}
```

So when I receive AlertData from observable I directly bind it to another observer, which works fine. But before binding it to another observer, I wanted to get the '**actionStream**' and get events from it.

So, this is how I emitting the AlertData:

```swift
let alertStream = PublishSubject<AlertData>()
alertStream.onNext(***)
```

This is the receiving part:

```swift
alertStream.bind(to: anotherObserver).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But before binding alertStream to anotherObserver, I wanted the actionStream which is inside the AlertData and receive any events emitted from it. What is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let actionStream = alertStream
    .flatMap { $0.actionStream.asObservable() }
```

You might not actually want `flatMap` (which acts as a flat map merge) specifically. Look into the variations on flatMap and see which one is most suitable for your particular situation: [RxSwift’s Many Faces of FlatMap](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c)